# Windows To Go USB pendrive-can it see the local hard drive

Tags: windows

Before I purchase the Windows-to-go pen drive, does anyone know if I boot Windows 8 from windows-to-go pen drive, can I access the laptop local hard disk? The reason is that if the end user can access his local hard disk after booting from Windows-to-go, it makes the option of allowing them working from home using their own computers out of window, if a new security policy is enforced.

--edit--

I dont think this is off topic. This is a new feature in Windows 8 Ent edition, which can change the way IT provision OS, e.g. if Windos-to-go feature can achieve what we want, then employees/contractors can work from home using their own computers as if they are company ones, without breaching any company security policy. If this is a viable approach, it may reduce company expenditure and possibly save time re-imaging machines.

Comment: [Windows To Go is a new feature in Windows 8 Enterprise Edition that enables you to provision a USB drive with a complete, managed Windows 8 system image.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36184) Doesn't appear to be off topic here.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed. It is on-topic.

Comment: Question flagged for re-opening and reopened.

Answer (score 5):

Windows-To-Go by default will boot with the system drive offline, but leave any additional data drives online. You can manually enable the disks through Disk Management as Administrator.

[From the Windows-To-Go FAQ:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592680.aspx#wtg_faq_san4)

> I’m booted into Windows To Go, but I can’t browse to the internal hard
>   drive of the host computer. Why not?
>
> Windows To Go Creator and the recommended deployment steps for Windows
>   To Go set SAN Policy 4 on Windows To Go drive. This policy prevents
>   Windows from automatically mounting internal disk drives. That’s why
>   you can’t see the internal hard drives of the host computer when you
>   are booted into Windows To Go. This is done to prevent accidental data
>   leakage between Windows To Go and the host system. This policy also
>   prevents potential corruption on the host drives or data loss if the
>   host operating system is in a hibernation state. If you really need to
>   access the files on the internal hard drive, you can use diskmgmt.msc
>   to mount the internal drive.